# Elasticsearch nested search - must not include

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having docs containning nested list

```
fixed_fields: [
    {
       id: 12,
       value: "someValue"
    },
    {
       id: 38,
       value: "someValue2"
    },
]
```

Now I need to find all documents that **don't have** fixed field with `id = 38`

I've tried:

```
            "bool":{
              "must":[
                {
                  "nested":{
                    "path":"fixed_fields",
                    "filter":{
                      "bool":{
                        "must_not":[
                          {
                            "term":{
                              "fixed_fields.id":38
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
```

But I got all documents having any fixed_fields in response, including the ones with id 38.

I'm using elastic in version 2.4.6, and I don't have option to upgrade it

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
{
 "bool": {
    "must_not": [{
        "nested": {
            "path": "fixed_fields",
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "fixed_fields.id": 38
                }
            }
        }
    }]
  }
}
```